# Unity not working in default user account

Tags: unity, 11.10

I have been using Oneiric since beta 1 release. After yesterday's update unity has stopped appearing. I did update a few minutes back too, but still it's not working with my default account. Surprisingly it works with 'Guest' login and a new administrator type account which I am using now. In my default account I am greeted with a blank screen. Going to tty1 and typing `unity` or `unity --reset` did not make any difference.

Comment: For me, Unity start working for updated user profile after deletion of ~/.gconf/compiz-1 and ~/.gconf/compizconfig-1

Comment: Do you mean ~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1 and ~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1 ?

Comment: Update: Yes. With the appropriate path, this DOES fix the blank screen problem.  Thank you Extender.  FYI: This was a problem with ubuntu 11.10 logging in as Unity (3D).  Before this, I had to login using unity 2d. And yes, the unity plugin must also be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have been in the same situation. What had happened for me yesterday (after updating) is that for some reason the Unity plugin was disabled due to keyboard shortcut conflicts. I tried unity --reset, but it didn't help.

So here's one thing you could check:

1. Enter CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager)
   1a. If you don't have it, run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Check that Unity plugin is enabled.
3. If not, try to enable it. If it asks a lot of questions about conflicts, just click on "Turn off ..." on all of them, that means some other plugins use those shortuts, but Unity should have the priority.

Not sure you're in the same boat, but might be worth checking.

-EDIT-
I misread, I could at least enter the desktop with no unity and launch a terminal with CTRL + ALT + T. If you just get a blank screen then this might be something else.